# Bool must be always returning NULL(if statement ignoring true or false)

Tags: c++11

I need to know why I am always returning NULL in the following context(for example no matter if I say "Yes", or "No", for any of the questions I am getting null( I assume because the question process repeats when it runs) even though I say no in main. I'm trying to get it to do this: for all invalid answers I return null, if null start over the question process, if answer was valid I return either true or false, if true continue, if false quit program.

```
 bool question1()
{
    string answer2;
    cout << "Are you 18 or older and have a valid Driver's License? Yes or No: ";
    getline( cin, answer2);
    transform(answer2.begin(), answer2.end(), answer2.begin(), ::tolower);
    cout << endl;
    if( answer2 == "yes")
    {
        cout << "Alright! " << endl << "You are set for registration. Please fill out the registration form. ";
        return true;
    }

    else if( answer2 == "no")
    {


        cout << "Do you know someone else who is 18 or older that can register? Yes or No ";
        getline( cin, answer2); 
        transform(answer2.begin(), answer2.end(), answer2.begin(), ::tolower);
        if( answer2 == "yes")
        {
            cout << "Good, then please continue the process in their place. Please fill out the registration form";
            return true;
        }
        else if( answer2 == "no")
        { 
            cout << "Please come back later when you have the appropriate personel";
            return false;
        }



        else
        {
            cout << "The answer given was invalid. Please give a valid answer. " << endl << endl ;
            return NULL;
        }

    }



    else
    {
        cout << "The answer given was invalid. Please give a valid answer. " << endl << endl;

        return NULL;


        }

 void registerPerson( array< string, nameSize > namesOfPeople, array< string, idSize > idlen)
{
    string pName;
    string dLicense;
    static int i = 0;
    static int b = 0;
    static int c = 0;
    unsigned int x = 1;


    cout << endl << endl << "REGISTRATION FORM:" << endl << endl << "------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Please" << endl << "enter the following: \n \n";
    cout << "Name: ";
    getline( cin, pName );

    for ( int j = i; j<=800; ++ j )
    {

        namesOfPeople[j] = pName;
        cout << namesOfPeople[j];
        i = i + 1;

        break;

    }

        cout << endl;

    while( x = 1)
    {
        cout << "Driver\'s Licence Number( Must be 9 characters long, no dashesh ): ";
        cin >> dLicense;
        if ( dLicense.length() < 9 || dLicense.length()> 9 )
        {
            cout << "The entered number was invalid. Please try again";
        }

        else
        {
            for ( int a = i; c<=800; ++ a )
                {

                    idlen[a] = dLicense;
                    cout << idlen[a];
                    c = c + 1;

                    break;
                }



        }
    }
}





}

{

    int main()
            array< string, nameSize > names = {};
            array< string, idSize > ids = {};

    carShare mycarShare1;










    carShare mycarShare2;
    mycarShare2.welcomeMessage();

    mycarShare2.question1();

    if( mycarShare1.question1() == NULL)
    {
        mycarShare1.question1();
    }

    else if( mycarShare1.question1() == true)
    {
    mycarShare1.registerPerson(names, ids);
    }


    else
    {
        return 0;
    }




    system( "PAUSE" );
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: please don't return NULL unless it is a pointer (in your case, a bool)

Comment: Ok..so how am I supposed to make it so that:

for all invalid answers, start question process over, if true continue with program, if false quit the program?

-Thanks

Comment: Just tested the code and it works for "yes" as input, note that your `NULL` will be converted to boolean `false` when returning tho so your error handling can't work the way it currently is.

Comment: A `bool` can hold only one of two values, `false` and `true`. If you need to indicate three distinct results, either use something other than `bool` (such as an `enum` with three elements), or throw an exception for the exceptional case.

Comment: @Keith Thompson so you are saying a bool cannot return a function itself

bool someFunction()



{
  return someFunction2();

}

Comment: @Shinji-san it can't return `NULL` or other values that aren't `false` or `true`. If you're talking about my recursive answer you're calling `question1()` again and then returning the bool this function returned to you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably change it to handle invalid input within `question1()` itself. An easy way to start the question over again is letting `question1` call itself again on invalid input until it gets a valid one like here (I put comments at all the changed places.):

```
bool question1()
{
    string answer2;
    cout << "Are you 18 or older and have a valid Driver's License? Yes or No: ";
    getline( cin, answer2);
    transform(answer2.begin(), answer2.end(), answer2.begin(), ::tolower);
    cout << endl;
    if( answer2 == "yes")
    {
        cout << "Alright! " << endl << "You are set for registration. Please fill out the registration form. ";
        return true;
    }

    else if( answer2 == "no")
    {


        cout << "Do you know someone else who is 18 or older that can register? Yes or No ";
        getline( cin, answer2); 
        transform(answer2.begin(), answer2.end(), answer2.begin(), ::tolower);
        if( answer2 == "yes")
        {
            cout << "Good, then please continue the process in their place. Please fill out the registration form";
            return true;
        }
        else if( answer2 == "no")
        { 
            cout << "Please come back later when you have the appropriate personel";
            return false;
        }



        else
        {
            cout << "The answer given was invalid. Please give a valid answer. " << endl << endl ;
            return question1(); // call itself again on invalid input.
        }

    }



    else
    {
        cout << "The answer given was invalid. Please give a valid answer. " << endl << endl;

        return question1(); // call itself again on invalid input.


    }


}

int main()
{
    array< string, nameSize > names = {};
    array< string, idSize > ids = {};

    carShare mycarShare1;

    carShare mycarShare2;
    mycarShare2.welcomeMessage();

    bool answer = mycarShare2.question1();

/*  if( answer == NULL) we don't need this anymore if we handle errors inside question1()
    {
        mycarShare1.question1();
    }
*/
    if( answer == true) // notice the change to if instead of else if here.
    {
        mycarShare1.registerPerson(names, ids);
    }


    else
    {
        return 0;
    }


    system( "PAUSE" );
    return 0;

}
```

Another way to do the same without recursion would be a `do... while` loop, here's a version of only `question1()` with a loop:

```
bool question1()
{
    string answer2; // has to be declared before the loop.
    do
    {
        cout << "Are you 18 or older and have a valid Driver's License? Yes or No: ";
        getline( cin, answer2);
        transform(answer2.begin(), answer2.end(), answer2.begin(), ::tolower);
        cout << endl;
        if( answer2 == "yes")
        {
            cout << "Alright! " << endl << "You are set for registration. Please fill out the registration form. ";
            return true;
        }

        else if( answer2 == "no")
        {


            cout << "Do you know someone else who is 18 or older that can register? Yes or No ";
            getline( cin, answer2); 
            transform(answer2.begin(), answer2.end(), answer2.begin(), ::tolower);
            if( answer2 == "yes")
            {
                cout << "Good, then please continue the process in their place. Please fill out the registration form";
                return true;
            }
            else if( answer2 == "no")
            { 
                cout << "Please come back later when you have the appropriate personel";
                return false;
            }

        }

    }while(answer2 != "yes" && answer2 != "no"); // loop as long as the input is invalid.

}
```

=====================================

Edit:

As clarification to it printing multiple times, here's the culprit in your original code:

```
mycarShare2.question1();

if( mycarShare1.question1() == NULL)
{
    mycarShare1.question1();
}

else if( mycarShare1.question1() == true)
{
    mycarShare1.registerPerson(names, ids);
}


else
{
    return 0;
}
```

`mycarShare2.question1()` is a function call, you were calling your function 3 times in that part. What you'd want was probably saving it in a bool variable and only test in the if/else statements after that, like this:

```
bool answer = mycarShare2.question1();

if( answer == NULL)
{
    mycarShare1.question1();
}

else if( answer == true)
{
    mycarShare1.registerPerson(names, ids);
}


else
{
    return 0;
}
```

Note: this is just to show it the way you probably expected it to be executed in your original code and not a solution. As said `bool` can only be `true` or `false` and the check for `NULL` isn't needed at all. (See my solutions above.)

Comment: Thank you, I've added the changes. but why does it print twice?

http://snag.gy/oHvPT.jpg

Thanks again

Comment: oh, oversaw sth in your program. you're calling `mycarShare2.question1()` before the if condition and then inside it again. Fixed that now, look at my new if condition inside `main()`

Comment: Wait so you are saying if I did something like if( mycarShare1.question1() == true ), means I have to run the function all over again? I thought it just checks the value of whatever was returned, not run it all over again?

Thank you

Comment: @Shinji-san put an edit about your function calls at the end of my answer again. (Think I got to learn to better describe stuff looking at how long that answer already got now.)